# How to develop a critical standpoint?

Tags: literary-criticism

I'd like to know how people write reviews in which they criticize and express their views on such a literary work (Any type).
If I don't like something, I just end up saying that I didn't like it, I don't know how to express my opinion

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. We would like to help you, but your question is currently rather broad and ambiguous. Could you please edit it to address the following points? (1) It is not entirely clear to me what you mean by criticising and reading with a critical perspective. Do you mean (a) writing a book review or (b) doing literary analysis. Reviews are much more about appreciation (and may include the description of weak points), whereas literary criticism is much more about analysis and interpretation.

Comment: (2) What genre do you have in mind? Novels, plays, short stories and poems are described using different sets of literary terms and at different levels of detail (typically due to the work's length). For this reason, I strongly recommend that you focus your question on a specific genre. (3) Is your question mainly about how to *read* for criticism or a review or about how to *write* criticism or a review?

Comment: This is still rather broad. "How can I develop a critical standpoint?" is a different question than "How do other people write reviews?". Trying to extend this to all forms of literature is, as @Tsundoku pointed out, going to make this difficult. And, there's still the problem that people go through *years of higher education* to develop their ability to express their views on literary works (even if they scope their studies to a particular sub-field, which this question does not) - so how could anyone manage to teach all of that in a single answer?

Answer (score 2):

Read more.  Take classes especially that teach techniques of literary analysis such as deconstruction, reader response, etc.  Even a creative writing course that might teach 'scansion' for instance, that would help with poetry.

The more experience you gain in academia, and in life, the clearer this answer will become.  As in everything else in life, by knowing yourself and your values, you can more easily express your opinion on other things.